# Existence of a particular arithmetic function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

**Prelude** (Disclaimer: This paragraph has no relevance to the actual question, but tries to illustrate the motivation behind my actual elementary question.) During the last days I wondered about the construction of certain Automorphisms of the Galois field extension $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p\vert \mathbb{F}_p$, where $\mathbb{F}_p$ denotes the [field of prime order $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) and $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ its algebraic closure. In particular I tried to construct a counterexample to the [Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) for non-finite Galois field extensions. For this I showed that the fixed point set of the Automorphism subgroup $\langle\mathrm{Fr}\rangle$ (generated by the Frobenius Automorphism $\mathrm{Fr}\colon x \mapsto x^p$) is only base field $\mathbb{F}_p$. If one now shows that this is a *proper* subgroup of the Galois group, we have a counterexample to the classical Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory. Using some field theory one can show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p \cong \bigcup_{d\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ and I reduced the problem to the construction of a Automorphism
$$
\psi\colon \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p\to\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p, \psi\vert_{\mathbb{F}_{p^d}} = \mathrm{Fr}^{m(d)}
$$
where $m\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a function such that $\psi$ is well-defined and $\psi \notin\langle\mathrm{Fr}\rangle$. This question can be reduced onto a simple artihmetic problem which forms my actual question.

**Question** Is there a function $m\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that

1. $d\vert m(d\cdot k) - m(d)$
2. $d \mapsto (m(d)\mod d)$ takes at least two different values?

**Remark** I have already resolved my original problem, namely the construction of some Automorphism as above which is no constant multiple of the Frobenius Automorphism, but by slightly different methods. Nevertheless, I am curious if a function $m$ as given above exists.

Comment: By $(m(d) \mod d)$ I mean the remainder of division after dividing $m(d)$ by $d$. This condition rules out "non-triviality" of the function $m$. In particular $m(d) = d$ does not fulfill this condition since $(m(d)\mod d)$ would be constant zero.

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. We map $d$ onto $(m(d)\mod d)$ and consider the image under all $d \in \mathbb{N}$. This image should contain at least two elements.

Comment: Then isn't $(2)$ equivalent to the simpler statement: $d\not\mid m(d)$ for some $d\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not equivalent since the remainder of division may as well be non-zero but constant, right?

Comment: But if $r$ is the map $d \mapsto (m(d)\mod d)$, then $r(1)=0$, so if $r$ is not identically zero, then $r$ is not constant.

Comment: First fix a prime $\ell$. Select an $\ell$-adic integer $m_\ell=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i,\ell}\ell^i$. For each exponent $t$ set $m(\ell^t)=m_\ell$ (may want to reduce it modulo $\ell^t$ because it makes no difference). If $d=\prod_j \ell_j^{t_j}$ is the factorization of $d$, let $m(d)$ be the unique solution (modulo $d$) to the congruences $m(d)\equiv m(\ell_j^{t_j})\pmod {\ell_j^{t_j}}$ for all $j$. This way your condition $(1)$ is automatic. The resulting automorphism is not a power of Frobenius if for at least one prime $\ell$ there are infinitely many non-zero coefficients in $m_\ell$.

Comment: Often your $(1)$ is rephrased to read $m(r)\equiv m(s)\pmod s$ whenever $s\mid r$, and $(2)$ to read: there does not exist an integer $m$ such that $m\equiv m(d)\pmod d$ for all $d$. Comes to the same. Anyway, the automorphism group is uncountable.

Comment: @quasi Yeah, you're right :D

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a very nice construction! The existence of the $m(d)$ follows by the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Correct, Peter. CRT is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, there are lots of easy ways to satisfy the conditions.

As a simple example, if $m:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ is given by 
$$m(n) = n+1$$
then, for all positive integers $d,k$, we have
$$m(kd) - m(d) = (kd+1) - (d+1) = (k-1)d$$
which is a multiple of $d$.

Thus, condition $(1)$ is satisfied.

Then, letting $r:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be given by 
$$r(d) = (m(d)\;\text{mod}\;d)$$
we have
\begin{align*}
r(1) &= (2\;\text{mod}\;1)=0\\[4pt]
r(2) &= (3\;\text{mod}\;2)=1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $r$ is not constant.

Thus, condition $(2)$ is satisfied.